# Host environment variables with docker stack deploy

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I was wondering if there is a way to use environment variables taken from the host where the container is deployed, instead of the ones taken from where the `docker stack deploy` command is executed. For example imagine the following `docker-compose.yml` launched on three node Docker Swarm cluster:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    deploy:
      mode: global
    environment:
      KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=${JMX_HOSTNAME} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099"
```

The `JMX_HOSTNAME` should be taken from the host where the container is actually deployed and should not be the same value for every container. 
Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, this works when you combine two concepts:

1. Swarm [node labels](https://docs.docker.com/config/labels-custom-metadata/), of which Hostname is one of the built-in ones.
2. Swarm [service go templates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#create-services-using-templates), which also work in stack files.

This would pull in the hostname to the ENV value of DUDE for each container to be the host that it's running on:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    environment:
      DUDE: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
```

Comment: Your solution actually works but it doesn't answer completely to my answer. Suppose I have a non-built-in variable that I want to read? Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, you should learn about Swarm node labels or host labels. Host labels are set in /etc/docker/daemon.json but not used often in a Swarm. Swarm labels are set via `docker node update` with `--label-add` and `--label-rm` and set any key/value you want :)

Comment: Then you can access it in the same way but with "labels" in the middle `.Node.Labels.LabelName`

Comment: I tried this method but it doesn't work. This is what i did: sudo docker node update --label-add ip='192.168.121.59' q687wox1uet33k4ubfvfa6p74. I then used this label in my compose file in environment section: environment:
- KAFKA_HOST_IP: "{{.Node.Labels.ip}}". Started stack: sudo -E docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml service. Got error-> desc = expanding env failed: expanding env "KAFKA_HOST_IP={{.Node.Labels.ip}}": template: expansion:1:7: executing "expansion" at <.Node.Labels.ip>: can't evaluate field Labels in type struct { ID string; Hostname string; Platform template.Platform }

Comment: if I use "KAFKA_HOST_IP={{.Node.Hostname}}" instead, it works. So, any custom label is not working. It seems that the "Labels" child is not present in the document. Seems like an issue of what first "." resolves to.

Answer (score 6):

It works if you run the docker command through [env](https://linux.die.net/man/1/env).

```
env JMX_HOSTNAME="${JMX_HOSTNAME}" docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack
```

Credit to [GitHub issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30251) that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: This is the correct answer for substituting variables in a stack yml file. It is a different problem then adding to container environment

Comment: How in the world does this work? `env JMX_HOSTNAME="${JMX_HOSTNAME}"` would be interpolated by a shell prior to docker seeing it. So, docker would see `env JMX_HOSTNAME=master_host_env_value docker ...`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

I found another way for when you have many environment variables. The same method also works with `docker-compose up`

```
sudo -E docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack
```

instead of

```
env foo="${foo}" bar="${bar}" docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack
```

---

`sudo -E` man description;

```
   -E, --preserve-env
               Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to
               preserve their existing environment variables.  The
               security policy may return an error if the user does not
               have permission to preserve the environment.
```