# Pass dynamic values to each node when deploying with Docker Stack in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, go-templates, docker-stack

I need to deploy a docker stack on several nodes in docker swarm. There are some dynamic values like the path to the ssl certificates which is different for each worker node. I know that I can't pass the values in environment variables because all of the nodes will get the values extracted from the manager node environment.

I searched and I found another question in StackOverflow addressing the same issue. Here is the [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025686/host-environment-variables-with-docker-stack-deploy)

The solution stated that I should use the command below for each node to set the values.

```
docker node update --label-add key=value <node-id>
```

My problem is when I want to read the values in `docker-compose.yaml` file I get the error:

`service proxy: undefined volume "{{.Node.Labels.Chain}}"`

I deploy using the command:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yaml stack_name
```

Here is the `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - connector

  proxy:
    image: myusername/myrepo:${VERSION}
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    volumes:
      - "{{.Node.Labels.Chain}}:/fullchain.pem"
      - "{{.Node.Labels.Key}}:/privkey.pem"
      - "${ERROR_LOG}:/err.log"
    ports:
      - "${HOST_PORT}:${CONTAINER_PORT}"
    networks:
      - connector

networks:
  connector:
```

I tried different values for version like `3` or `3.4` but didn't help.

I ran the command `docker node inspect <HOST_NAME>` and here are the results related to `Labels` section:

```
        "Spec": {
            "Labels": {
                "Chain": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem",
                "Key": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem"
            },
            "Role": "manager",
            "Availability": "active"
        }
```

I tried different values for the mount key in `docker-compose.yaml` file like `{{.Node.Spec.Labels.Chain}}` but they didn't help either.

I'd be grateful if anyone can help me solve the issue.

results of `docker version`:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.7
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        2d0083d
 Built:             Thu Jun 27 17:56:23 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.7
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       2d0083d
  Built:            Thu Jun 27 17:23:02 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Comment: Right now I can see the label values using the command:
```docker inspect --format {{.Spec.Labels.Chain}} <HOST_NAME>```
but my problem is now that `docker-compose` does not execute the template and I'm getting the error `Named volume "{{.Spec.Labels.Chain}}:/fullchain.pem:rw" is used in service "proxy" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.`.

Comment: Looks to me as if you wanted to reinvent the wheel: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/ Imho, you let the swarm do something your application should handle.